# Is it possibile to access ( not copy ) files in my remote from my local machine?

Tags: python, ssh

I want to access a `random forest` estimator that I trained and saved on the remote machine. The pickled estimator is 2.4 gigs and my local machine is low on space so i can't use `scp` to download the file in my local. Is it possible that python can access (read) the file kept in the remote and load it in its RAM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The [paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko) module allows to open a file like object to a remote file. From the [Paramiko SFTP doc page](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html):

> `class paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient(sock)`
>
> SFTP client object.
>
> Used to open an SFTP session across an open SSH Transport and perform remote file operations.
>
> Instances of this class may be used as context managers.
>
> ...
>
> `file(filename, mode='r', bufsize=-1)`
>
> Open a file on the remote server. The arguments are the same as for Python’s built-in file (aka open). A file-like object is returned, which closely mimics the behavior of a normal Python file object, including the ability to be used as a context manager.

Answer (score 1):

Would a [RAM disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive) be an option? It is not python specific, but on the os level, but in case there is no better solution, it might be helpful.
(Sadly i don't have the necessary reputation to comment, therefore i'll add this as an anwser.)

Comment: A shared folder on the remote machine? Which operating system is running on the two hosts?

Comment: @darthn this would be a nice long term solution, but for my current needs I would accept the other answer as it is exactly what I want without diving into OS specific commands to setup RAM disk.